# Changing North/South latitude values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

In Python I'm dealing with a couple of large csv's containing geographical data in different kinds of formats for latitude and longitude. I settled on converting them to decimal degrees. My issue is that some files are already formatted this way, but with a direction (N,S,E,W) attached at the end of each individual coordinate. Also, the south and west coordinates are not yet negative, and they should be when in decimal degrees.

I was initially using regex to filter these directions out, but can't figure out a way to attach a negative to South and West coordinates before dropping them. I am using *pandas* to read the csv in.

Example coordinates:

```
Latitude, Longitude
30.112342N, 10.678982W
20.443459S, 30.678997E
```

```
import *pandas* as pd

df = pd.read_csv("mydataset.csv")

if df['Latitude'].str.endswith('S'):
   df.Latitude = -float(df['Latitude'].str.strip('S'))

else:
   df.Latitude = float(df['Latitude'].str.strip('N'))
```

Depending on how I tweak it, I get different errors, the most common being:

*Attribute error: 'Latitude' object has no attribute 'strip'.*

I've tried changing the dtype to string, among other methods, with no luck. I can filter out the directions with regular expressions, but can't discern what the direction was to change to negative if necessary. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. The current code will indeed produce an error, but not the one you shared in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `.apply()`. The value `df['Latitude']` is the full column, so you can't work on all of them at once for this sort of operation.

Instead, do something like this:

```
def fix_latitude(x):
    """Work on individual latitude value X."""
    if x.endswith('S'):
        x = -float(x.strip('S'))
    else:
        x = x.strip('N')
    return x


df['fixedLatitude'] = df.Latitude.apply(fix_latitude)
```